# Date issue in Client(Flex) and Serverside(JAVA) issue

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, blazeds, cairngorm

I have a date porblem in flex applications.

while submit the date in flex applcation (28/09/2010 10:00:00 AM) as a string, the date is cobnverted in to Date object inserver side and displayig the result.

But i install the server in other location (Ex:- USA) .Now i am passing the date from india(28/09/2010 10:00:00 AM) But the date in the USA is different. How to convert the date? Conversion should be happen in client side or server side? How the server knows the date which is given by client is the current date?

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the date as UTC ( universal time ) on the server , and when retrieved on the client use the Date class timeZoneOffset property to set the date to the client's current location